# Mongoose pull and get pulled item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to remove an item from a nested array in Mongoose and return it so I can push it to another array in my object.

Here's how an instance of my `Room` Model looks:

```
{
  name: "Foo",
  boardBucket: {
    currentBoardId: 1234,
    items: [
      {
        boardItems: [
          {
            id: 1,
            data: "path1"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            data: "path2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        boardItems: [
          {
            id: 3,
            data: "path4"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            data: "path5"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    undoedItems: []
  }
}
```

What I want to do is remove `path1` from `boardItems` and push it into `undoedItems`

#### Using `$pull` to remove

I'm using the following to remove `path1` from `boardItems`.

**Note:** The below is within my `roomSchema.methods` so `this` refers a particular `Room` instance of the `roomSchema`

```
      // where `i` is the index of the "board" I'd like to operate
      // on and `itemId` the `id` of the path I want to pull
      // - Using this dot notation because of nested array
      // - Note that `${i}` is simply an ES6 interpolated template
      //   literal that has nothing to do with mongo's positional 
      //   operator

      var path = `boardBucket.items.${i}.boardItems`;
      var updateOp = {};
      updateOp[path] = { id: itemId };
      this.update({
        $pull: updateOp
      }, (err, result)=> {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
```

#### The question

How can I get the "pulled" item so I can `$push` it into `undoed` items?

#### The `roomSchema`

In case it helps, here's my `roomSchema`

```
var roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    boardBucket: {
      currentBoardId: String,
      items: [
        {
          active: Boolean,
          boardId: String,
          boardItems: Array,
          undoedItems: Array,
          viewPosition: String
        }
      ]
    }
});
```

Comment: you can pull and push `updateOp` in same query right?

Comment: Err, not quite sure what you mean - You mean in the same block of code?

Comment: `this.update({
        $pull: updateOp, $push:updateOp
      }`

Comment: what is that going to `$push` though? - E.g I'm looking to move this `{ id: 1, data: "path1" }` from `boardItems` to `undoedItems` - The `updateOp` is not the *actual value* of the object I want to move, it's just the *path that leads to the item* I want to pull

Comment: ok what  updateOp looks like?

Comment: `{ boardBucket.items.0.boardItems: {id: 1}`

Comment: I think you should use `findAndModify` which returns old document and then traverse the `boardItems` array to find your object